# MySQL SELECT to get total sales by payment method and status

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have some sales data as below:

```
SELECT bv.sale_time
     , amount_due
     , round(sum(amount_paid), 2) as paid
     , m.payment_method_id
     , m.method
     , bt.payment_status
FROM basket_amount_due bv 
  JOIN basket bt USING(basket_id)
  LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
  JOIN payment_method m USING(payment_method_id)
GROUP BY bv.basket_id;

+---------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| sale_time           | amount_due | paid    | payment_method_id | method            | payment_status |
+---------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| 2021-09-18 12:19:04 |    1170.00 | 1170.00 |                 1 | CASH              | paid           |
| 2021-09-18 12:19:39 |     756.60 |    0.00 |                 1 | CASH              | due            |
| 2021-09-18 12:20:22 |    1115.50 | 1000.00 |                 1 | CASH              | partial        |
| 2021-09-18 12:21:47 |     990.00 |  990.00 |                 4 | Cash on Delivery  | paid           |
| 2021-09-18 12:23:33 |     698.40 |    0.00 |                 4 | Cash on Delivery  | due            |
| 2021-09-18 12:29:45 |    2070.00 | 2070.00 |                 2 | Credit/Debit Card | paid           |
+---------------------+------------+---------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.004 sec)
```

My question is, Now I need to get total sales by payment method and payment status. That mean I want,

- **total cash sales** (= cash(paid) + cash(partial paid) + Cash on Delivery
  (paid))
- **total credit sales** (= cash(due) + cash(partial due) + Cash on    Delivery
  (due))
- **total cash on delivery sales** (= Cash on Delivery    (paid) +    Cash
  on Delivery (due))
- **total card sales** (Card (paid))

Using the output of above query, my expecting output by numbers as below:

- **Totoal Cash Sales**      = (1170.00 + 1000.00 + 990.00)
- **Total Credit Sales**     =
  (756.60 + (1115.50 - 1000.00) + 698.40)
- **Total Cash on Delivery Sales**
  = (990.00 + 698.40)
- **Total Card Sales**       = (2070.00)

**NOTE:** As shown in the equation (payment method (payment status)). `Ex: (cash (paid))`

This is the query I have so far.. Hope somebody may help me out to figure this out.

```
SELECT DATE(bv.sale_time)
     , CASE 
        WHEN p.payment_method_id IN (1, 2) 
          THEN sum(amount_due) 
          ELSE 0 
        END AS total_cash_sales
     , CASE p.payment_method_id
        WHEN 4 THEN sum(amount_due) ELSE 0 END AS total_credit_sales
FROM basket_amount_due bv 
  JOIN basket bt USING(basket_id)
  LEFT JOIN basket_payment p USING (basket_id)
  JOIN payment_method m USING(payment_method_id)
WHERE DATE(bv.sale_time) = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY p.payment_method_id;
```

Comment: Have you considered using 5 sub-selects in your query?

Comment: ` 1 AND 2` is always true. `DATE` not needed to wrap `sale_time`.  Write a `case` expression that evaluates to a unique number for each of your 4 categories and then `group by` that expression identifier.

Comment: @danblack Can I see an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you go back to the principle component of each total:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(bt.payment_method_id IN (1,4), amount_paid, 0)) as cash_sales,
  SUM(IF(bt.payment_method_id IN (1,4), amount_due - amount_paid, 0)) as credit_sales,
  SUM(IF(bt.payment_method_id = 4, amount_due, 0) AS COD_Sales,
  SUM(IF(bt.payment_method_id = 2, amount_due, 0) AS card_sales
FROM basket_amount_due bv 
  JOIN basket bt USING(basket_id)
WHERE DATE(bv.sale_time) = CURDATE()
```